# Delete Change Log for 1 contact

Tags: contacts, logging, civicontact

We are trying to delete the change log for 1 user. We want to complete remove their address and information on our system. There a way to delete the change log for 1 contact in CiviCRM?

Comment: You could take a look at what the GDPR extension offers but that seems a bit of a mission for a single contact.

Comment: I do actually have that extension installed and ran "Forget me" for the contact I wanted. It changed everything but kept the change log.

Comment: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/22361/data-protection-gdpr-deleting-from-logging-tables/22421#22421 shed any light for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to do.
If you want the complete removal of the contact, together with related entities (like address, activities, event participations etc.), then permanently deleting the contact will delete all the associated entities.

If you just want to remove the change log for that 1 contact without deleting the contact, you can run a simple SQL query to delete it. For a contact with the contact id 57 you would run this:

```
DELETE FROM `civicrm_log` WHERE entity_table LIKE 'civicrm_contact' and entity_id = 57
```

Beware, if you used something like Drupal webforms, then the data can still be there in the webform submissions, even though you deleted it form CiviCRM.